# Ruby Increment array from certain starting point

Tags: arrays, ruby, numbers, iteration

I feel this is a super simple query but I'm having a real tough time with immutable nums in my arrays.

I'd like to have a super simple method, which increments numbers in an array by distributing them from the max value.

eg [1,3,5,1] becomes [1,3,0,1] and then iterates upwards and back through to create [2,4,1,3]

what I currently have is the following

`arr = [1,3,5,1]`

with a method of

```
def increment_from_max_value(arr)
    max = arr.max
    max_index = arr.index(max)
    arr[max_index] = 0

    while max >= 0
      arr[max_index..-1].each do |element|
        element = element += 1
        max = max -= 1
      end
    end
end
```

Currently the array isn't even updating and just returns the original values. Which I believe is due to the immutability of FixNums in Ruby, but with a method like `map!`, which is able to modify those values, I can't get it to loop back through from a certain starting point like `each` will.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: In your example you find `5` as the maximum value, which you change to `0`. Then you "allocate" the `5` to the values, evidently one at a time. After `4` such allocations you obtain `[2,4,1,2]`. I assume any left over from the original `5` (here `1`) is allocate to the last element of the array. Correct? What would be your desired return value if the array were `[1,2,3,2,1]`? Would it be `[2,3,0,3,1]`?

Comment: Hey Cary

Almost. Rather I'm trying to distribute the elements in the array from the max value, starting from the following element and looping back through. 

So with an array of [1,2,3,2,1] it would become [2,2,0,3,2] having already incremented by a count of three, distributed across the following elements in the loop chain

Comment: It should not be necessary to read comments to understand a question. Not all readers read all comments and a comment to which you repond could be deleted in future, possibly leaving your comment meaningless. You therefore should clarify by edited your question.

Comment: @galacticmuffin are you trying to do a [mancala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mancala) game?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`divmod`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Numeric.html#divmod-method) to calculate the increase for each element and the leftover.

For a max value of 5 and array size of 4 you'd get:

```
5.divmod(4) #=> [1, 1]
```

i.e. each element has to incremented by 1 (first value) and 1 element (second value) has to be incremented by another 1.

Another example for a max value of 23 and 4 elements:

```
[1, 3, 23, 1]

23.divmod(4) #=> [5, 3]
```

each element has to be incremented by 5 and 3 elements have to be incremented by another 1:

```
    [  1,  3, 23,  1]
#     +5  +5  +5  +5
#     +1  +1      +1
# = [  7,  9,  5,  7]
```

Applied to your method:

```
def increment_from_max_value(arr)
  max = arr.max
  max_index = arr.index(max)
  arr[max_index] = 0
  q, r = max.divmod(arr.size)

  arr.each_index { |j| arr[j] += q }
  r.times { |j| arr[(max_index + j + 1) % arr.size] += 1 }
end
```

`arr.each_index { |j| arr[j] += q }` simply adds `q` to each element.

`r.times { |j| arr[(max_index + j + 1) % arr.size] += 1 }` is a little more complicated. It distributes the remainder, starting from 1 after `max_index`. The modulo operation ensures that the index will wrap around:

```
0 % 4 #=> 0
1 % 4 #=> 1
2 % 4 #=> 2
3 % 4 #=> 3
4 % 4 #=> 0
5 % 4 #=> 1
6 % 4 #=> 2
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the block variable `element` in `arr[max_index..-1].each do |element|` is changed by `element = element += 1` but that has no effect on `arr`.

You could achieve your objective as follows.

```
def increment_from_max_value(arr)
  mx, mx_idx = arr.each_with_index.max_by(&:first)
  sz = arr.size
  arr[mx_idx] = 0
  arr.rotate!(mx_idx + 1).map!.with_index do |e,i|
     begin_nbr = mx - i
     e += (begin_nbr <= 0 ? 0 : 1 + ((begin_nbr - 1)/sz))
  end.rotate!(-mx_idx - 1)
end
```

```
arr = [1,3,5,1]
increment_from_max_value(arr)
arr
  #=> [2, 4, 1, 3]
```

```
arr = [1,2,3,2,1]
increment_from_max_value(arr)
arr
  #=> [2, 2, 0, 3, 2]
```

After computing the maximum value of `arr`, `mx`, and its index, `mx_idx`, and setting `arr[mx_idx]` to zero, I rotate the array (counter-clockwise) by `mx_idx + 1`, making the position of `mx` last. That way the "allocations" of `mx` begin with the first element of the rotated array. After performing the allocations I then rotate the array clockwise by the same `mx_idx + 1`.

`begin_nbr` equals `mx` minus the number of indices that precede `i`; in effect, the portion of `mx` that remains "unallocated" at index `i` in the first round of allocations.

I can best explain how this works by salting the method with `puts` statements.

```
def increment_from_max_value(arr)
  mx, mx_idx = arr.each_with_index.max_by(&:first)
  sz = arr.size
  puts "mx = #{mx}, mx_idx = #{mx_idx}, sz = #{sz}"
  arr[mx_idx] = 0
  arr.rotate!(mx_idx + 1).
      tap { |a| puts "arr rotated to make mx position last = #{a}" }.
      map!.with_index do |e,i|
        begin_nbr = mx - i
        puts "e before = #{e}, i = #{i}, begin_nbr = #{begin_nbr}"
        e += (begin_nbr <= 0 ? 0 : 1 + ((begin_nbr - 1)/sz))
        e.tap { |f| puts "e after change = #{f}" }
      end.
      tap { |a| puts "arr after changes = #{a}" }.
      rotate!(-mx_idx - 1).
      tap { |a| puts "arr after rotating back = #{a}" }
end
```

```
arr = [1,3,5,1]
increment_from_max_value(arr)
mx = 5, mx_idx = 2, sz = 4
arr rotated to make mx position last = [1, 1, 3, 0]
e before = 1, i = 0, begin_nbr = 5
e after change = 3
e before = 1, i = 1, begin_nbr = 4
e after change = 2
e before = 3, i = 2, begin_nbr = 3
e after change = 4
e before = 0, i = 3, begin_nbr = 2
e after change = 1
arr after changes = [3, 2, 4, 1]
arr after rotating back = [2, 4, 1, 3]
  #=> [2, 4, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with the `while` loop. I did not investigate but you can see that this line `arr[max_index] = 0` mutates the array.

I don't know if I've understood the logic, but this should return the desired output:

```
def increment_from_max_value(arr)
  max = arr.max
  arr[arr.index(max)] = 0

  indexes = (0...arr.size).to_a.reverse
  max.times do
    arr[indexes.first] += 1
    indexes.rotate!
  end
end
```